# Yamaha not starting (see video)

Tags: motorcycle, ignition, starter, yamaha

Afternoon all,
I have a xmax 300 working perfectly until today when it did not start at all, I have sufficient power in the battery, every function working perfectly until I try to start it and it starts buzzing with everything going off with a weird sound (video in the link). Think its an electrical issue and will check the fuse but if you have any better idea or have seen that before, let me know!
many thanks
https://youtu.be/hZY2SWvzEjI

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you *know* there is sufficient power in the battery? How did you verify this?

Comment: It is normal for the LCD display to blank when you start it? They require hardly any power to function.

Comment: Most likely a battery not fully charged or a bad battery.

Comment: I have a tracker on my motorbike that gives me the level of the battery and can see that it is sufficient, it is not normal for the CD display to blank like that

Comment: Usually when the battery is low, at list the starter tries to start the bike very slowly, here it does not at all... will check the fuse tonight